# API VK account.lookupContacts

Tags: vkontakte-api

Как работать с методом `account.lookupContacts`, чтобы получить `id` cтраницы, зная номер телефона, к которому она привязана?

Создал Standalone-приложение. Получил `access_token`.
Перехожу по ссылке:

```
api.vk.com/method/account.lookupContacts.json?contacts=тут_номер_телефона_который_ищу&service=phone&mycontact=&return_all=0&fields=photo_100,photo_50,common_count&v=5.27&access_token= тут_ключ_авторизации
```

Но появляется ошибка:

```
{«error»:{«error_code»:5,«error_msg»:«User authorization failed: no access_token passed.»,«request_params»:[{«key»:«oauth»,«value»:«1»},
```

Comment: Покажите, каким образом Вы получаете `access_token`.

Comment: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=ИД_Моего_Приложения&scope=offline,group,photos,wall&display=page&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html

Comment: Нужно было добавить https://                                                                                 https://api.vk.com/method/account.lookupContacts.json?contacts=тут_номер_телефона_который_ищу&service=phone&mycontact=&return_all=0&fields=photo_100,photo_50,common_count&v=5.27&access_token= тут_ключ_авторизации                                                         Но тогда все равно появляется ошибка, но другая:                                 {"error":{"error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: no access to call this method"

Comment: При получении токена попробуйте явно указать `scope=friends`.

Comment: А запрос попробуйте такой `https://api.vk.com/method/account.lookupContacts.json?contacts=номер_телефона&service=phone&return_all=0&fields=photo_50,photo_100&v=5.27&access_token=токен`.

Comment: Сделал запрос, но снова натыкаюсь на ошибку                             {"error":{"error_code":5,"error_msg":"User authorization failed: no access_token passed."                                                                                                   Испытайте, может у Вас получиться добыть запрашиваемую информацию таким образом.

Comment: Локализуйте проблему. Сначала получите токен. Попробуйте проверить корректность полученного токена, выполнив другие запросы. Если другие запросы выполняются, то значит токен получен верно и проблема уже во втором запросе, если нет – ошибка при получении токена. У меня сейчас нет возможности воспроизвести это самому.

Answer (score 1):

При получении токена, нужно указывать в scope friends и offline(для получения бессрочного по времени действия токена)

Например:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?
client_id=6666666                  # ИД вашего приложения
&scope=friends,offline
&display=page
&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html
&response_type=token
&v=5.60
```

Также при запросе, укажите соответствующую версию API в строке в участке &v=5.27